# Multiple svnserve instances on network share

Tags: svn, svnserve

we have SVN configured using a custom tunnel. Every time I commit, svnserve is started on a remote Linux machine. Thus it is possible to have several svnserves running simultaneously accessing the same repository on a network. I have found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/111002/is-it-safe-to-run-two-instances-of-svnserve-on-one-repository-or-only-one), but it seems somewhat different. I know that accessing the repository via file:// is dangerous. How about our setup?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much how the svn+ssh protocol works, it's fine.